# ArcGIS Pro PostgreSQL SSH connection string

Tags: arcpy, postgresql, arcgis-pro, sql-server, migration

I am involved in a project where a SQL Server-base application is being retired and replaced with a PostgreSQL/PostGIS-based tool under development. There is a large amount of cross-checking to be done related to data migration, so being able to write queries across the old/new databases would be helpful.

To that end, I am trying to establish a connection to the new PostgreSQL DB from ArcGIS Pro. Connecting to both databases from SSMS is not possible because Linked Servers are unavailable from our production server (though we are also looking into linking from a test server).

My pgAdmin connection depends on SSH, but neither the ArcGIS > Catalog > New Database Connection dialogue nor the `arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management()` (and related methods) appear to accept SSH-related parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: SSH can be done to Amazon EC2 http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-server-amazon/10.2-final/index.html#//00rq00000022000000 what is your setup?